# Como faço para adicionar um objeto diferente em uma lista sempre que usar o add?

Tags: java, estrutura-de-dados, objetos, lista-encadeada

Estou tendo problemas para adicionar um objeto diferente em uma lista de objetos sempre que uso o add dela, eu sei qual o problema mas não sei como concerta-lo, segue o código
Classe lista

```
public class Lista {

    NodeLista inicio;
    NodeLista fim;

    public Lista (){
        inicio = null;
        fim = null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return inicio == null;
    }

    public int size(){
        if(isEmpty()){
            return 0;
        }
        NodeLista aux = inicio;
        int cont = 1;
        while(aux.proximo != inicio){
            cont++;
            aux = aux.proximo;
            if(aux == inicio){
                break;
            }
        }
        return cont;
    }

    public void add(NodeTree arvore){
        NodeLista novo = new NodeLista(arvore);
        if(isEmpty()){
            inicio = novo;
            fim = novo;
            inicio.proximo = null;
            fim.proximo = null;
        }else {
             fim.proximo = novo;
             fim = novo;
             fim.proximo = null;


        }
    }

    public boolean validarElemento(String elemento){
         NodeLista aux = inicio;
         for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
             if(aux.arvore.elemento.equals(elemento)){
                 return true;
             }
             aux = aux.proximo;
         }
         return false;
     }
 }
```

Classe NodeTree

```
public class NodeTree {
    String elemento;
    Lista filhos;

    public NodeTree(String elemento){
        this.elemento = elemento;
        filhos = new Lista();
    }

}
```

Classe NodeLista

```
public class NodeLista {
    NodeTree arvore;
    NodeLista proximo;
    NodeLista anterior;

    public NodeLista(NodeTree arvore){
        proximo = null;
        anterior = null;
        this.arvore = arvore;
    }

}
```

Main

```
public class MainTree {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Lista lista = new Lista();
        System.out.println(lista.size());
        NodeTree arvore = new NodeTree("1");
        lista.add(arvore);
        NodeTree arvore2 = new NodeTree("2");
        lista.add(arvore2);
        arvore2.elemento = "3";
        System.out.println(lista.inicio.arvore.elemento);
        System.out.println(lista.inicio.proximo.arvore.elemento);
        System.out.println(lista.size());
    }

}
```

Console

0
1
3
2

Saída desejada

0
1
2
2

Toda vez que adiciono um obj nodetree na lista e altero pelo proprio objeto o elemento dele, estou alterando na lista tbm, ha alguma forma de não alterar na lista?

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54237/discussion-on-question-by-turiba-malafaia-como-faco-para-adicionar-um-objeto-dif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como está gerando alguns problemas, vou colocar o trecho do comentário (editado) que possivelmente ajudou a solucionar o problema:

Acho que se puder ser complementado, melhor para todos.

> Quando você fez: arvore2.elemento = "3", você alterou o atributo
>   elemento do nó que já estava dentro da lista, e não apenas o nó
>   externo. A lista guarda referências para objetos que estão na Heap
>   (logo: lista.inicio == arvore). Em Java, se você passa um objeto como
>   parâmetro, é sempre a referência do objeto e não o valor, diferente de C que existe a possibilidade de passagem por parâmetro e por valor.

Recomendação de leitura: [O que são e onde estão o “stack” e “heap”](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3797/o-que-sao-e-onde-estao-o-stack-e-heap)